# How to add custom meta fields to moodle course elements?

Tags: moodle, moodle-api, edx

I have a question: I'm trying to connect interrelated elements between two courses (calculus and physics) for students, and first step I'm going to do is to add custom fields for course materials and assignments, on which I'm going to keep id's for the elements of the correlated course element.

For example: student fails the test on Classical Mechanics and he's redirected on materials about derivatives on Calculus.

So, two question here:

1) how to add custom fields in Moodle.

2) how to request them via REST API in Moodle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> how to add custom fields in Moodle.

You should [develop your own plugin](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Tutorial#Let.27s_make_a_plugin), and it is not what can be explained in two words.

> how to request them via REST API in Moodle?

This is also [part](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Adding_a_web_service_to_a_plugin) of custom development